# ReactJS How to update specific components only on page load

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, real-time-clock

In ReactJS I created an analogue clock as a component that updates every second using: -

```
componentDidMount () {
    setInterval(()=> {
      this.setClock()
    }, 1000)
  }
```

I also have a component that updates on page load with random names. Since I have added the analogue clock on an interval timer, everything that would reload on refresh/page load is updating every second. How do I render my other components only on initial page load?

Comment: Do you want to make other components child of this clock?

Comment: I placed setInterval in a section where I am adding more components as children. Can I stop them from being rendered each second?